# Assign object to a member variable in C++ class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting

```
error: use of deleted function ‘PropertyLink& PropertyLink::operator=(PropertyLink&&)’
```

When I try to assign an object to a member variable in the class constructed.

I have 2 class definitions, `PropertyLink` and `NodeBlock`. and I want to create an object of `PropertyLink` inside `NodeBlock` when constructing a `NodeBlock` object.

Following are the class definitions

`PropertyLink.h`

```cpp
class PropertyLink {
    
   public:
    PropertyLink(unsigned int);
    PropertyLink();
};
```

`PropertyLink.cpp`

```cpp
#include "PropertyLink.h"

PropertyLink::PropertyLink(unsigned int propertyBlockAddress): blockAddress(propertyBlockAddress) {};
PropertyLink::PropertyLink(): blockAddress(0) {};
```

`NodeBlock.h`

```
#include "PropertyLink.h"
class NodeBlock {
   public:
    PropertyLink properties;

    NodeBlock(unsigned int propRef) {
        properties = PropertyLink(propRef);
        // properties(propRef); // error: no match for call to ‘(PropertyLink) (unsigned int&)’
        // properties = new PropertyLink(propRef); // tried this too none of them worked
    };
};
```

In the compiler output, there is a note saying

```
note: ‘PropertyLink& PropertyLink::operator=(const PropertyLink&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
[build]     9 | class PropertyLink {
```

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. While it may have been answered before (*if* you know what to google for), it is not a bad question per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the copy/move assignment operator of `PropertyLink` is not usable. You can (and should) initialize `properties` directly instead of assigning it in constructor's body.

You can use member initializer list.

```
class NodeBlock {
   public:
    PropertyLink properties;
    NodeBlock(unsigned int propRef) : properties(propRef) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, It worked! Can you please explain why I can't assigned to a member variable in the constructor's body, What is `copy/move assignment operator` ?

Comment: @TMKasun It's because `PropertyLink` can't be assigned, not just in the constructor's body. Even  I don't know why they're `delete`ed, maybe you're not showing all the definitions of `PropertyLink`. And see [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) and [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).